# Cannot find Mac OS X C++ Linker on Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I am trying to link SDL2 to my library but the Mac OS X C++ Linker setting does not appear on the Eclipse Settings window.

I have spent hours looking for it and how to make it appear or how to install it.
To be honest, I don't even know if I can install this in the way that i think.

This is what I am looking for:

[image: This is what I am looking for]

This is what my Settings window looks like:

[image: This is what my Settings window looks like]

Comment: Why aren't you using Xcode? Even so, you need to install Xcode. I think the command line tools are made available to the command line automatically these days. It used to be an extra feature you needed to set up in `Downloads` preferences pane.

Comment: If you are building a static library, it does not link to other libraries. Only loadable binaries need to be linked: applications and dylibs.